# Algorithms for transforming an ordered tree to a directed acyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, parsing, tree, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let's say I have a programming language where I can write:
x = f(g(1), h(1)) in this case the directed acyclic graph will show the dependencies of calculation like in a spreadsheet (assuming non recursive expressions):

```
 1
| \
g  h
 \ /
  f
```

This is a simple example but it turns interesting trying to "compress" more complex expressions within a DAG. The goal here is optimizing the number of recalculations based on the dependencies.

What algorithms and papers are available for dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit more specific, it's Local Common Subexpression Elimination. An algorithm is given in [Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811), "6.1.2 The Value-Number Method for Constructing DAG's"

Answer (score 3):

Compiler writers call this problem [common subexpression elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination). Every compilers textbook worth its salt covers this topic.

Without control flow, you should be able to do something simple akin to [hash consing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing).